# Can't render styles received from API using [ngStyle]

Tags: javascript, angular, styles

I have an API that is returning the following;

```
{
  titleBarBackgroundStyle: "background: #2c3e50"
}
```

I want to bind the value via inline style like so

```
<div [ngStyle]="client?.titleBarBackgroundStyle"></div>
```

But I am getting the following error:

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'background: #2c3e50'

I, unfortunately, can't change the format being sent from the API as it is tied to a legacy application.
Is there any way to display the styles, would I have to use regex?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code, you need to use the following format  {key: value} the the key must be the css property  `'background-color'` then in value you must put the returing value with out property.

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-color': client?.titleBarBackgroundStyle}"></<div>
```